# How to use variables inside Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to build a RegEx in JavaScript that matches a word but not part of it. I think that something like \bword\b works well for this. My problem is that the word is not known in advance so I would like to assemble the regular expression using a variable holding the word to be matched something along the lines of:

```
r = "\b(" + word + ")\b";
reg = new RegExp(r, "g");
lexicon.replace(reg, "<span>$1</span>"
```

which I noticed, does not work. My idea is to replace specific words in a paragraph with a span tag. Can someone help me?

PS: I am using jQuery.

Comment: If you think `\bword\b` will work, why are you creating it as `\b(word)\b`?

Comment: because I want to capture the given word which will not always be "word".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in regular expressions **and** in strings.

Since you are assembling the regular expression from strings, you have to escape the `\`s in them.

```
r = "\\b(" + word + ")\\b";
```

should do the trick, although I haven't tested it.

You probably shouldn't use a global for `r` though (and probably not for `reg` either).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works as expected! by the way, I am not using globals, that was just simple mock code for the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You're not escaping the backslash. So you should have:

```
r = "\\b(" + word + ")\\b"; //Note the double backslash
reg = new RegExp(r, "g");
```

Also, you should escape special characters in 'word', because you don't know if it can have regex special characters.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Your answer is also correct but I saw the other first and it worked, I bumped it up though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And don't write expressions in the regexp variable, because it does not work!

Example(not working):

```
 var r = "^\\w{0,"+ maxLength-1 +"}$";    // causes error
 var reg = new RegExp(r, "g");
```

Example, which returns the string as expected:

```
 var m = maxLength - 1;
 var r = "^\\w{0,"+ m +"}$";
 var reg = new RegExp(r, "g");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
r = "(\\\b" +word+ "\\\b)"
```