# Jquery Match with variables

Tags: jquery, preg-match

I'm trying to match a string with a variable, this variable comes from a text field

What I got:

```
if( v[1].match(/Piet/i) ){
    console.log( v );
}
```

This works, but now i have to add my val in it.
I have search around and found this topic:

- [How to use variables inside Regular Expression in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916833/how-to-use-variables-inside-regular-expression-in-javascript)

now I trying what they say in the topic:

```
if( v[1].match("\\(" + val + ")\\i") ){
    console.log( v );
}
```

Now i don't get any results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work :

```
if( v[1].match(new RegExp(val, 'i'))) {
    console.log( v );
}​
```